# Adding Databases to Availability Group

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, high-availability

I'm attempting to add databases to an existing availability group using automated seeding but I randomly receive this error: "Seeding Check Message Timeout".  I'm pulling this error message from sys.dm_hadr_automatic_seeding.

I've attempted to add databases one at a time or several at once.  Either way results in the above error.  I've also attempted using script and SSMS gui.

Comment: What happens if you grant the permission or set the seeding option to the secondary replica again?

Comment: I'd suggest to try restore the DB manually on the "new" server and then just try a "join only".